# Generating spectrogram for band-pass filtered wav file python

Tags: audio, python, image-processing, bandpass

I have some .wav files of heart sounds. I want to apply band-pass filter [20Hx 100 Hz]. Then generating  PCG images size of 560x420 pixels and RGB format. How could i do this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [scipy](https://www.scipy.org) you can easily:

- bandpass signals, for instance with [scipy.signal.butter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html)
- obtain a spectrogram, using for instance [scipy.signal.stft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) (or [LTFAT, The Large Time-Frequency Toolbox (LTFAT) in Python](https://pypi.org/project/ltfatpy/))
- scale the values of this 2D array so that each channel has values between $0$ and $1$
- reshape the array into a $560\times 420$ grid, eg with [scipy.ndimage.affine_transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html) or [scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform.html)
- save the image, but I don't know the PCG format

Comment: PCG means heart sounds

Comment: So this is not an image format. Any standard image format would do